# sql query doubling on sum function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have been building a query and I am missing something.
This query **doubles** a value that it should not double.
Good news is that It returns the correct amount. 
Bad news is that amount is added to itself.
I think its the group by but I am not sure.

The problem is on derived table (temp3).
*What I have tried*:
1)I have tried rearranging the group by clause but that does not help but I am open to suggestions.
2)I tried running the derived table(temp3) on its own and it runs without the doubling value.
3)I re-worte the joins between the (temp1) with (temp3)and(temp2) respectively to use modern syntax but no joy either way but I am open to suggestions.

```
SELECT
temp1.last_name,
temp1.employee_number,
temp3.assignment_action_id,
temp3.effective_date,
sum(temp3.result_value)problem_value,
sum(temp2.result_value)result_value
from 
(SELECT papf.last_name,
        papf.first_name,
        papf.employee_number,
        paa.assignment_action_id
from    apps.per_all_people_f papf,
        apps.PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_F paaf,
        pay_assignment_actions paa,
        PAY_PAYROLL_ACTIONS ppa
where   paaf.person_id           = papf.person_id
AND     papf.employee_number     like  NVL(:EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,'%')
AND     paaf.assignment_id       = paa.assignment_id
AND sysdate BETWEEN papf.effective_start_date AND papf.effective_end_date
AND sysdate BETWEEN paaf.effective_start_date AND paaf.effective_end_date
AND paa.assignment_action_id = paa.action_sequence
AND paa.payroll_action_id = ppa.payroll_action_id
AND( ppa.Effective_date BETWEEN  '01-jul-2019' AND '31-jul-2019'
or  ppa.Effective_date BETWEEN  '01-feb-2020' AND '29-feb-2020')) temp1,

-----------------------------------------------
                    (SELECT pet.element_type_id row_id ,
                     sum (to_number (prv.result_value)) result_value,                     
                     prr.assignment_action_id ,pact.effective_date,
                     pec.classification_name base_classification_name

  FROM apps.pay_element_types_f_tl pettl ,apps.pay_element_classifications_tl pectl ,
  apps.pay_element_types_f pet ,apps.pay_element_classifications pec ,
  apps.pay_input_values_f piv ,apps.pay_run_result_values prv ,
  apps.pay_run_results prr ,apps.pay_assignment_actions asact ,
  apps.pay_payroll_actions pact 
  WHERE pec.classification_id = pectl.classification_id 
  AND pet.element_type_id = pettl.element_type_id 
  AND prr.element_type_id = pet.element_type_id 
  AND prr.status IN ('P','PA') AND pact.payroll_action_id = asact.payroll_action_id 
  AND asact.assignment_action_id = prr.assignment_action_id AND pet.classification_id = pec.classification_id 
  AND piv.element_type_id = pet.element_type_id AND prv.input_value_id = piv.input_value_id 
  AND prv.run_result_id = prr.run_result_id AND piv.name = 'Pay Value' AND piv.uom = 'M' 
  AND pact.effective_date BETWEEN piv.effective_start_date AND piv.effective_end_date 
  AND pact.effective_date BETWEEN pet.effective_start_date AND pet.effective_end_date
  -------------------------------
  AND (pact.effective_date BETWEEN  '01-jul-2019' AND '31-jul-2019'
                    or   pact.Effective_date BETWEEN  '01-feb-2020' AND '29-feb-2020')
  AND pec.classification_name IN ('Statutory Deductions', 'Deductions',
                                  'Voluntary Deductions','Involuntary Deductions')
  AND nvl(prv.result_value,0) != 0
  ------------------------------
  AND not exists (SELECT pet1.element_type_id from pay_element_types_f pet1 
                    where pet1.element_name in ('Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM1', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM2',
                    'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM3', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM4',
                    'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM5', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM6', 
                    'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM7', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM8', 
                    'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM9', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM10', 
                    'ZA_Tax_On_Multiple_Lump_Sums', 'ZA_Tax_On_Lump_Sums', ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM1',
                    ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM2', ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM3',
                    ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM4', ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM5', 
                    ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM6', ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM7',
                    ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM8', ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM9', 
                    ' Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM10' ) 
                    AND pet1.element_type_id = pet.element_type_id AND pet1.legislation_code = 'ZA') 
                    GROUP BY prr.assignment_action_id,pact.effective_date                   
                    ,pec.classification_name
                    ,pet.element_type_id)temp2                   
,
(SELECT pet.element_type_id row_id ,
                     nvl (pettl.reporting_name ,pettl.element_name) report_name ,

                     sum (to_number (prv.result_value)) result_value ,
                     pet.processing_priority ,prr.assignment_action_id ,pact.effective_date,
                     pec.classification_name base_classification_name

  FROM apps.pay_element_types_f_tl pettl ,apps.pay_element_classifications_tl pectl ,
  apps.pay_element_types_f pet ,apps.pay_element_classifications pec ,
  apps.pay_input_values_f piv ,apps.pay_run_result_values prv ,
  apps.pay_run_results prr ,apps.pay_assignment_actions asact ,
  apps.pay_payroll_actions pact 
  WHERE pec.classification_id = pectl.classification_id 
  AND pet.element_type_id = pettl.element_type_id 
  AND prr.element_type_id = pet.element_type_id 
  AND prr.status IN ('P','PA') AND pact.payroll_action_id = asact.payroll_action_id 
  AND asact.assignment_action_id = prr.assignment_action_id AND pet.classification_id = pec.classification_id 
  AND piv.element_type_id = pet.element_type_id AND prv.input_value_id = piv.input_value_id 
  AND prv.run_result_id = prr.run_result_id AND piv.name = 'Pay Value' AND piv.uom = 'M' 
  AND pact.effective_date BETWEEN piv.effective_start_date AND piv.effective_end_date 
  AND pact.effective_date BETWEEN pet.effective_start_date AND pet.effective_end_date
  AND (pact.effective_date BETWEEN  '01-jul-2019' AND '31-jul-2019'
                    or   pact.Effective_date BETWEEN  '01-feb-2020' AND '29-feb-2020')
  AND pec.CLASSIFICATION_NAME in ('Normal Income','Allowances','Direct Payments','Lump Sum Amounts')
  AND nvl(prv.result_value,0) != 0
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT pet1.element_type_id from pay_element_types_f pet1 
                    where pet1.element_name in ('Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM1', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM2',
                    'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM3', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM4',
                    'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM5', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM6', 
                    'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM7', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM8', 
                    'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM9', 'Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM10', 
                    'ZA_Tax_On_Multiple_Lump_Sums', 'ZA_Tax_On_Lump_Sums', 'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM1',
                    'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM2', 'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM3',
                    'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM4', 'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM5', 
                    'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM6', 'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM7',
                    'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM8', 'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM9', 
                    'Addl Medical Tax Credit Used on LMPSM10' ) 
                    AND pet1.element_type_id = pet.element_type_id AND pet1.legislation_code = 'ZA')
                    GROUP BY pec.classification_name ,prr.assignment_action_id ,pet.processing_priority
                    ,nvl (pettl.reporting_name ,pettl.element_name) 
                    ,pet.element_type_id,pact.effective_date)temp3
 where  temp1.ASSIGNMENT_ACTION_ID  =  temp3.ASSIGNMENT_ACTION_ID
 AND    temp1.ASSIGNMENT_ACTION_ID  =  temp2.ASSIGNMENT_ACTION_ID
 group by temp3.assignment_action_id,temp2.assignment_action_id,temp1.last_name,
        temp1.employee_number,temp3.effective_date,temp2.effective_date;
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Learn to use modern, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: I would test each subquery in isolation to make sure it did not return duplicated `ASSIGNMENT_ACTION_ID` values etc. Also the exercise of rewriting the comma joins to proper `JOIN` syntax can flush out some missing conditions (I had a look at some and didn't find any unjoined tables, but I don't have your data model).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I would love to use that modern join syntax but part of the requirements do not allow this. So what i then did was to translate the syntax to modern standards in order to work backwards should i find the answer. That beared no fruits. What worked was to bottle certain parts into a function and have only one group by function. inside the the.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I apologise for not submiting test data. I have found a solution and all i had to do was to bottle temp1 and temp2 and temp3 into 1 function that took assignment_action_id and a keyword signifying salary or deductions. This function then returned the total answer without multiplying the total salary or total deductions.

Answer (score 0):

You are already doing a `sum inside temp2 and temp3` maybe that is the cause of the issue. Can you please revisit the below

```
  sum (to_number (prv.result_value))
```

Also try using `distinct` in each select statement to remove duplicates

Comment: I thought it was that in my initial troubleshoot but then since temp2 and temp3 are basically the same query. temp2 returns the amounts without doubling the amount. I have removed the sum in temp3 to no avail.

Comment: try using distinct in each select statement